# Use Google Apps Script Execution API with API keys and Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-apps-script-api

I want to create a web application for my client and use Google drive to store information.
Since it's impossibe to integrate a web application from google apps script in my own website I try to use Google Apps Script Execution API and Javascript to make the interaction between my website and Google Drive.

I find out some exemple like this one : 
https://mashe.hawksey.info/2015/10/google-sheets-as-a-database-authenticated-insert-with-apps-script-using-execution-api/
I do be able to reproduce this example but it use an Auth authentification.

I would like to use Google Apps Script Execution API without Auth authentification but with simple API keys.

Is it possible ? And do you have an example to illustrate this.

Thank you for your help,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do that. Check [this guide about web deployment using apps script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web). You just need to run the web app as your own user (parameter *Execute the app as*). But you will only be able to get access to your own google Drive which may not be that useful. If you want to access others' people Drive then you must run the web app as the current user but this will prompt for permissions (the first time the user access your application).