# Google Apps Script Execution API - Calling app is Apps Script - Apps Script to Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have two scripts in different domains, I would like to fetch data from one to the other.

I've found Script Execution API to be useful, however they don't provide any example GAS to GAS. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/rest/quickstart/target-script

Any suggestion/guidance on how to accomplish such thing?

Comment: as a general rule you should've posted something that you already tried.

Now, ontopic, here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app you can find docs about how to work with drive

If i understand correctly you want to access folders from another account..
If this is the case using this https://jsfiddle.net/6da2oboe/ will get you a list of all the folders you have the rights to view. I tried it and it works. You just have to have reading rights.

Maybe you should refine it a bit to view them in a more "readable" way

Comment: This is what i've tried before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38999993/two-scripts-different-domains-merge-data

Answer (score 2):

This answer might be helpful. what i have done is that created a cloud platform project and created two standalone project, one contains the calling script and other has the method you want to call and must be deployed as a API Executable.

**IMPORTANT**: Both these project must be associated with the Cloud Platform Project.

For associating the projects to Cloud Platform's project , in script editor do this, **Resources --> Cloud Platform Project**. You'll see the dialog box which has input box having placeholder *Enter Project Number Here*, here put the Cloud Platform's project number and do the same for other project as well.

Now as i have followed google's quick start tutorial for EXECUTION API. i have a target script (Script containing your method) as follows:

```
/**
 * The function in this script will be called by the Apps Script Execution API.
 */

/**
 * Return the set of folder names contained in the user's root folder as an
 * object (with folder IDs as keys).
 * @return {Object} A set of folder names keyed by folder ID.
 */
function getFoldersUnderRoot() {
  var root = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  var folders = root.getFolders();
  var folderSet = {};
  while (folders.hasNext()) {
    var folder = folders.next();
    folderSet[folder.getId()] = folder.getName();
  }
  return folderSet;
}
```

NOTE: This script must be deployed as a API Executable. In project you must have enabled the Google Execution API.

Now the calling script,

```
function makeRequest(){
  // DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  var access_token=ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var url = "https://script.googleapis.com/v1/scripts/{YourScriptId}:run";
  var headers = {
    "Authorization": "Bearer "+access_token,
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  };
  var payload = {
    'function': 'getFoldersUnderRoot',
    devMode: true
  };
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    method: "post",
    headers: headers,
    payload: JSON.stringify(payload),
    muteHttpExceptions: true
  });
  Logger.log(res);  
}
```

On first line inside function you can see i have commented out the Drive API call. I did that because the calling script and target script must have the same scope.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use [Execution API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/rest/api) to fetch data from one domain to other. From the documentation, it consists of a single scripts resource, which has a single method, `run`, that makes calls to specific Apps Script functions.

> The run method must be given the following information when called:
>
> - The [ID of the script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution/rest/v1/scripts/run#path-parameters) being called.
> - The [name of the function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution/rest/v1/scripts/run#request-body) within the script to execute.
> - The list of parameters the function requires (if any).

Here is an example from [GitHub](https://gist.github.com/revolunet/f2ac1755cec306596dcb):

```
var script = google.script('v1');
var key = require('./creds.json');
var jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(key.client_email, null, key.private_key, ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'], null);

jwtClient.authorize(function(err, tokens) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return;
  }
  script.scripts.run({
    auth: jwtClient,
    scriptId: 'script-id',
    resource: {
      function: 'test',
      parameters: []
    }
  }, function(err, response) {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
    console.log('response', response);
  })

});
```

You can also check this [related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34682857/use-google-apps-script-execution-api-with-api-keys-and-javascript) on how to use Google Apps Script Execution API and Javascript to make the interaction between website and Google Drive.